# Specify a Triangle's Vertices based on radius and center coordinate

Tags: c#, xna, geometry

Is there a code formula for this? I am using C# and XNA, and in my class I have an array of three vectors (representing the vertices of the triangle), as well as a separate vector coordinate.

I plan to update these positions in the loop as it escalates further towards the top of the screen.

I'd ask maths.stackexchange.com, but seeing as how this applies to programming (and I personally am better at reading code as opposed to math itself - I'm still taking Algebra in school), I think it would make more sense for me to ask it here.

**Edit** 
Yes, I am looking for an equilateral triangle. Or any triangle, for that matter. It doesn't matter what it is. All I am looking for is a formula; is that so hard to ask for?

**Teh Problem**

Basically, the problem I am trying to solve is to shoot a triangle out of my player (think *Space Invaders*; i.e., the triangle acts as a ray from the ray gun). What I need is a formula of code which will allow the triangle to be rendered based on its center position and radius, as the triangle will move upwards on its `Y` coordinate. I have the draw calls, and they work, but the problem is that the triangle when put in a for loop draw iteration (where the center vector position - on the `Y` coordinate - is incremented by `N`)  simply *sits* next to the player's position when being drawn.

Comment: Are you asking for an equilateral triangle?  Otherwise it's hard to say unless you can more about the dimensions of two of the sides at least, plus a starting angle for one of the points (assuming 0 at the top?), maybe keeping track of the side in radians so the scaling would be auto as the radius grew.  If you had 2 radians then you could just calculate the points from that. You might consider asking a math teacher at school, as you've gone way over algebra now.  I'm sure they'd be happy to help.

Comment: You can't write code for a mathematical problem unless you have decided and formulated the mathematical problem to solve. It is clear you have not gone even that far. Often the simple act of being able to clearly describe what you are trying to do will help you to write the code you need. But you can't do that until you understand the problem you want to solve.

Comment: The question and its title are confusing.  If you have an array of 3 vectors representing the vertices of the triangle, why do you have to 'specify' them from the centre and radius of (what I presume is) the circumcircle of the triangle ?

Comment: Yes, equilateral triangle definitely.

Comment: @woodchips: actually, I have encountered the problem I am trying to solve. Originally I was able to shoot triangles out of my player, the problem being that these triangles would only work if they were packed into a `List<Vector3>` in multiples. I would like to figure out how to get this to work *without* such methods.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark
Well, the main reason for this is so that I can simply *move* the position of the triangle using a center `X,Y` vector, and simply calculate the vertex drawing of the triangle dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for... 
the angle is the orientation of the triangle...
this build a triangle....

```
void BuildTriangle(Vector2 Center, float Radius, float Angle, Vector2[] tri)
{
   for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
   {
      t[i].X = Center.X + Radius * (float) Math.Cos(Angle + i * 2 * MathHelper.PI/3);
      t[i].Y = Center.Y + Radius * (float) Math.Sin(Angle + i * 2 * MathHelper.PI/3);
   }
}
```

if you want to move it, add to the center a velocity vector and rebuild it...